# LISTAGG columns empty when query via ADODB recordset and Amazon Redshift (x64) Driver

Tags: vba, postgresql, amazon-redshift, adodb

I am executing SQL that creates two columns using the `LISTAGG` function and it works just fine in [Aginity](https://www.aginity.com/products/aginity-workbench/).

```sql
SELECT po_num::numeric AS po_num,
       MIN(tran_date) AS tran_date ,
       listagg(tran_date, ',') within
GROUP (
       ORDER BY tran_date DESC) AS all_rm_dates,
      listagg(rm_num, ',') within
GROUP (
       ORDER BY tran_date DESC) AS all_rm_numbers
FROM main.curr_rm
GROUP BY 1
```

I tried a few variations on the above SQL and none would return data for the LISTAGG columns in the ADODB `recorset.open` dataset. My standard process is to save the Aginity SQL file as a text file and assign the file contents to a string variable within the VBA code.  This process has worked great for the past two years.  Problem is the LISTAGG columns are all empty (but are not when SQL run in Aginity). ADODB `recordset.open` statement:

```sql
rs.Open sql, CN, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

The `recorset.open` with the matching SQL executes and does not cause an error.  Resulting records match between Aginity and the ADODB recorset except the `LISTAGG` columns. The `recordset.open` LISTAGG columns are empty. Can't figure our why. Unsure if it is a limitation with the Amazon Redshift x64 driver, ADODB, or my criteria in the `recordset.open` statement.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at stl_query (or stl_querytext) on Redshift and see what is actually being run.  I suspect that ADODB is getting confused by the 'within group" construct or the fact that Redshift uses "listagg()" instead of "string_agg()" as in postgres and not issuing the correct SQL.  You can confirm what is being run on redshift and where the issues likely lies.